How to solve the $\iint_D \frac{(x-y)^2}{1+x+y}dxdy$ where D is the trapezoid with edges $(1,0),(0,1),(2,0),(0,2)$ and using $u=1+x+y$ and $v=x-y$
I know that you need to find the Jacobian of $u,v$ and multiply it with the existing $f(x,y)$ inside the integral. But how can I then find the limits of integration for $u$ and $v$ after that since the new shape is not going to be a square? These are the lines that shape the $D$ if you do not want to work with points $y=0, x=0, y=-x+1, y=-x+2$. Also, $y=\frac{u-1-v}{2}$ and $x=\frac{v+u-1}{2}$ if you take these $u$ and $v$ and the absolute value of the jacobian is $\frac{1}{2}$!
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Transform the 4 points to the u-v plane, you get a trapezoid with parallel sides parallel to the v-axis. inner integral is $dv$ from $v=-u+1$ to $v=u-1$

Ok thanks a lot for the help WW1!
